# Document Library Sub Folder Access

Tags: document-library, permissions, folder, security-trimming, share

I have a question related to folder access in a document library in SP 2013.

I have a Document Library with a folder structure as follows:

```
Document Library
 -Folder A 
  -File 1
  -File 2
 -Folder B
  -File 3
```

If I grant access to File 1 to a user who's in a group that does not have access to the document library, they can access Folder A with a direct link and they will only see File 1 but NOT file 2, which is to be expected.

However if they open the Document Library containing both folders, Folder A is NOT displayed (which I'm assuming is because they do not have access to document library and the folders). This is a problem because there is no way for the user to drill down into the folder to find the file that they've been granted access to.

I believe this to be related to security trimming, as SharePoint is not correctly assigning the limited access to the folders in the Document Library.

Does anyone know if there is a site collection feature or site feature I need to disable/enable? I've tried disabling Limited-access user permission lockdown mode but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Creating Document Sets? As you can give individual access to each Document sets . Better option then using folders.

Comment: I have looked into that but the client wants to use the native SharePoint file structure in a document library to achieve this. 

To make matters worse, this used to "just work" in SharePoint 2010 and so the user expects the same functionality in SP 2013.

If I cannot find a way to update the folder permissions to correctly display limited access I believe I can replicate the functionality by making clever use of workflows, a web API that integrates with the site, and "dummy" documents shared to that user group which hold the folder URLs. I will update with this solution later if need be.

Answer (score 0):

It would pay to clarify if your view is set to Show or Hide folders.

Modify your view, then scroll down to the Folders Section.  Make sure "Show items inside folders" is checked rather than "Show all items without folders".

Comment: The view is set up appropriately.

In fact if I set the view to "Show all items without folders" the user gets a flat view where he/she can see all of the documents that have been shared with him/her.

However they still can't see the folder structure in that view (as is intended with that setting) so they have no idea what the parent folder(s) are because they still can't see the file structure.